# How to use Javascript to click a button upon onload

Tags: javascript, click, onload

I'd like for my page (https://fiftyallstars.com/tour.html) to load, and for the TOUR to start automatically. Right now visitors must click a button with id "starttour"

Here's what I've added so far, but it doesn't do the trick:

```js
 $(function () {
          window.onload = $('#starttour').click();
      });
```

```html
<a class="start-tour" href="#" id="starttour"><span class="two skinny" style="margin:10px 5px; width:290px; font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:4px;"><i class="fa fa-photo animated faa-pulse faa-slow"></i> Take a Detailed Tour</span></a>
```

Thanks for any help whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check the below snippet. Hope it helps
```

```js
var tourLink = document.getElementById('starttour');
window.onload=function(){
  document.getElementById("starttour").click();
};

tourLink.addEventListener('click', function () {
   console.log("clicked on page load")
});
```

```html
<a class="start-tour" href="#" id="starttour">
  <span class="two skinny" style="margin:10px 5px; width:290px; font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:4px;">
    <i class="fa fa-photo animated faa-pulse faa-slow"></i> Take a Detailed Tour
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. I think the issue was that the page was loading too slowly, so I added a pause feature.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I think the issue was that the page was loading too slowly, so I added a pause feature.